# Simple JavaScript Ellipses (...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alright people it's simple I am just not understanding something !

Basically, I have created an automatic JavaScript Ellipses after a certain amount of characters typed into a ID element.

It is working but only for one of them, I want it to work for all of the 12 spans just like how to first one is working.

Jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/86463ggt/

```
var myid=document.getElementById('title');
myid.innerHTML=myid.innerHTML.substring(0,10)+'...';
```

Thankyou for any help provided !

Comment: IDs should only be used once in a document. If you are using them more than once, use classes instead. Also, you should be looping through the results if you want to apply it to multiple elements

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question rather than linking to JSFiddle.

Comment: So you would need to select all the spans and loop over them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of document.getElementsById, use document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN") to apply that substring to all spans and getexpected result

```
var myid=document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")
for(var i=0;i<myid.length;i++){
myid[i].innerHTML=myid[i].innerHTML.substring(0,10)+'...';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/86463ggt/1/

Comment: Nice and simple but there's is a popup.

Comment: yes @Thomasfarley, i just kept it for testing..removed it now :)

Comment: Hope this works as expected for you :) now ...check updated fiddle now https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/86463ggt/2/

Answer (score 0):

IDs are supposed to be unique. You have two paths you can take here. You can either add a class to all of the elements to select them by (preferred) or you can just do a blanket select of all matching elements using your existing markup.

Here's my take on the first solution:

```js
// Define the function that'll do the truncating
function addEllipses(el, len) {
  var html = el.innerHTML;
  if (html.length > len) el.innerHTML = html.substring(0, len) + '...';
}

// Select all elements that are supposed to get truncated
var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('ellipses');

var i;

// Call our function on each target
for (i = 0; i < targets.length; i += 1) {
  addEllipses(targets[i], 10);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title" class="ellipses">The dog took a walk over the dange...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title2" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title3" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title4" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title5" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title6" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title7" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title8" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title9" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title10" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title11" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title12" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code allows you tell the function at what length you want to truncate (10 in your case).

If you run this code on your page you can then add the `ellipses` class to any elements you want to be truncated.

Here's the jquery version since you have that tag on the question:

```js
// Define the function that'll do the truncating
function addEllipses($el, len) {
  var html = $el.html();
  if (html.length > len) $el.html(html.substring(0, len) + '...');
}

// Select all elements that are supposed to get truncated
var $targets = $('.ellipses');

// Use map to loop through all elements and call our function on them
$targets.map(function (i) { addEllipses($targets.eq(i), 10); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title" class="ellipses">The dog took a walk over the dange...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title2" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title3" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title4" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title5" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title6" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title7" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title8" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title9" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title10" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title11" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="title12" class="ellipses">It is not working for this one :(</span>
  </div>
</div>
```